# SQL Trigger - DML statement Output Insert Error

Tags: sql-server

I am using Zapier to link results of a form to a MSSQL database table.
When a new row is added to the table I want to be able to insert that record into another table using a trigger. I have this trigger:

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[Add_New_Learner]
on [dbo].[ILR_New_Learner]
for Insert
as
insert into ILR (GIVENNAMES,FAMILYNAME,CURR_EMAIL)
select FirstName,LastName,EmailAddress
from inserted
```

However, when I try and add a new record I get this error.

> The target table 'ILR_New_Learner' of the DML statement cannot have
>   any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause
>   without INTO clause. (334)

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: That's not an error you can fix from the trigger side (aside from removing the trigger entirely).

Comment: I don't see any OUTPUT clause.  Is `ILR_New_Learner` table have any other trigger?

Comment: The query that is inserting to the table uses the OUTPUT clause. Because of this, SQL does not allow a trigger to be applied. The only options are to 1) remove the trigger. 2) Adjust the query that is inserting to the table (if possible).

Comment: @DanB - the point is, some other code (presumably some generated within `Zapier`) is running something like `insert into ILR_New_Learner (/*columns*/) output inserted.something values (1,2,3)` and getting the error. It's this trigger and the *other* code's use of `OUTPUT` that combine to produce an error, and you cannot fix it from the trigger side if you want to continue to have a trigger.